# Compatibilities between ROS and ubuntu BSP?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi people.
I'm looking forward to install an ubuntu BSP, but before that I would like to know if it is possible to install the ROS Hydro Medusa on it or any other release.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119551/compatibilities-between-ros-and-ubuntu-bsp?/) by [Origanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/11011/origanne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kamiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5346/kamiccolo/) on 2014-01-20**:
Could You be more specific on the board You trying to use?
Short googling came up with this wiki.ROS.org [manual](http://wiki.ros.org/IntelGalileo/How%20to%20install%20ROS%20Hydro%20on%20Intel%20Galileo) of installing Ubuntu + BPS + ROS Hydro on Intel Galileo. So, it appears, in general case it's possible :)

Still, You should consider using [rosserial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial) instead.

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-20**:
This should be a good start.
http://wiki.ros.org/hydro
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The core ROS team maintains ROS Hydro packages for Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04 for i386 and x86_64; these packages should work on most Ubuntu variants and BSPs for those architectures. See the [Ubuntu installation guide](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu) to get started.

I maintain some builds of ROS Hydro packages for Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04 for the armhf architecture, which supports most of the ARM boards currently on the market. Most boards ubuntu variants and BSPs, including Linaro/LUbuntu, work with these debs. The 13.04 builds are the most complete, so if you can find a BSP based on Ubuntu 13.04, that's probably your best bet. Once you have Ubuntu up and running, take a look at the [Ubuntu ARM installation guide](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/UbuntuARM)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2